# Wordpress : create dropdown list listing all the posts?

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, blogs

In a sidebar, I want to add a dropdown list listing all the posts created and which will be created. (automatically)
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqezx.jpg)

As you can see I don't know how to display automatically each category and the other posts ...Plus I just realize I need to add a button to go the selected post ? it 's complicated for me :'(

I tried with the grouplist html (so i can see the categories, then the posts for each category)

thanks for reading me

Comment: Your question sounds too general to me. I guess wp_query will help you: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this, maybe not the most elegant, would be to first loop through all the categories. Maybe store them in an array. Then use a for each loop to loop through all the categories in the array for posts of each category.